# css position right out of range of view

Tags: html, css

```css
#box_1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ee3e64;
}
#box_2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #44accf;
    right: 200px;
}
#box_3 {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #b7d84b;
}
```

```html
<div id="box_1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_3" class="box"></div>
```

Why is the blue box out of range. Is it not specifying it's position from the right?

Comment: You can simply remove `right: 200px;` from `#box_2` to make all three boxes similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A positive value to the `right` offset shifts it to the left. Try a negative value or use `left`.

**Explanation**

When an element uses `position: relative`, the positioning offsets are taken with respect to the original location of the element within the content flow.

In this example, when you use `right: 200px` on `#box_2`, the right edge of the element is shifted by 200px to the right of the original right edge position of the element, so the element shifts towards the left.  If you use a negative value, then the shift will be towards the right.

You can achieve a similar effect by using `left: 200px` instead.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position

```css
#box_1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ee3e64;
}
#box_2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #44accf;
  right: -200px;
}
#box_3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #b7d84b;
}
```

```html
<div id="box_1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_3" class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Can't we use positive `left: 200px;` instead of writing negative value?

Comment: @RobertRocha I added an explanation to the posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Relative** >
This keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have been had it not been positioned)

Look at these:

[image: Boxes positioned by CSS where Box 2 in the illustration is positioned relative and 20px from the left and top]

```
#two { position: relative; top: 20px; left: 20px; }
```

I believe you are following [this](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101) article? I advise you to read it to the end.